# Redirect uri while creating credentials

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, credentials

I am trying to run my webapp on local before hosting it on Google App Engine. I am trying to set up client credentials for using Google-OAuth. What **redirect uri** should I provide. I tried using "http://localhost:8000/" as redirect uri but it resulted in **OS Error** (OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted).

Comment: App Engine is Linux based. Your error message comes from Windows. Edit your question to be correct, include your code and more details.

Comment: Where are you calling the localhost:8000? Is it your redirect? What is listening on the port 8000 on your workstation?

Comment: @JohnHanley I was trying on my local system at the time of the error.

Answer (score 0):

are you using the gcloud dev_appserver.py? it sets up an admin console on port 8000, maybe that's what you are colliding with